# Quiero poner mapa de Google Maps en Android y obtengo el error: "could not find dependency com.google.android"

Tags: android, google-maps

He leído y he visto algunos vídeos sobre como hacerlo pero el problema aparece cuando empiezo a meter código, me salen muchos errores. 
Ya he instalado el Google Play Services y el Google USB Driver pero al intentar solucionar los errores e instalar lo que me pide me salta este error:

> "could not find dependency com.google.android".

Alguien puede ayudarme?
Muchas gracias.

---

He borrado la clase, xml y todo lo que tenía que ver con Google Maps y ahora tampoco me funciona el proyecto que anteriormente si me funcionaba.
También me da este error al intentar compilarlo.

Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/C:/Users/adminportatil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/adminportatil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/adminportatil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/adminportatil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/adminportatil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/adminportatil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.jar
>         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.pom
>         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.jar
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.pom
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.6.2/play-services-maps-11.6.2.jar
>     Required by:
>         project :app

Comment: Com.google.android, estas seguro? Me parece que no esta confiuradp correctamente tu Android studio

Comment: Gracias por agregar más información, Para agregar más información a tu pregunta usa la opción "editar".

Comment: creo que te has cargado demasiado cosa, crea un nuevo proyecto para ver que no sea otra cosa y a partir de aquí creas la actividad de mapas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad el problema es configuación de Android Studio, en este caso necesitas actualizar el `Android Support Repository` desde el SDK Manager.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al actualizar probablemente necesites actualizar otros componentes, pero en la terminal te agregara el enlace para realizar las actualizaciones pendientes.